# Can't print all Legend in a 3D graph with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a dataset like:

[image: dataframe]

I can't get the graph to print the 4 labels I'm plotting, the labels are the keys on this dictionary:

```
a = {'Pike':'red','Roach':'blue','Bream':'green','Perch':'orange'}
```

It will only print the first one:

[image: current figure with only first legend key]

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, show, draw, figure, cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

ax = Axes3D(fig) 
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

a = {'Pike':'red','Roach':'blue','Bream':'green','Perch':'orange'}
b = a.keys()
x = fish['Height']
y = fish['Width']
z = fish['Weight']

mp = ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=fish['Species'].apply(lambda x: a[x]), alpha=0.5, marker='o', s=50)
ax.view_init(azim=30)
ax.view_init(elev=15)
ax.set_xlabel('Height', fontweight ='bold')
ax.set_ylabel('Width', fontweight ='bold')
ax.set_zlabel('Weight', fontweight ='bold')
#ax.legend(a.keys(), bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1), loc=1)
legend = ax.legend(a.keys(), loc="upper left", title="Species",  ncol=4)
ax.add_artist(legend)
plt.title('Fish Features 3d', fontweight ='bold', size=40)
plt.show()
```

Comment: No data is presented, so there is no way to be sure, but four colors are colored for a single data. So I assume that only one legend is shown since it is a single data. So, if you need a legend for each color, you need to use a loop process with a condition for each color.

Comment: I applied your code based on the official matplotlib reference for validation. I'll share the code I created in [Colabratory](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1WaxoDQJZ46ILI3Vs3V0HN4_jaL41Wmem?usp=sharing). I will remove this comment if you confirm.